# How can I convert .obj files into a 2D array of [x,y,z] coordinates and color values?

Tags: 3d, models, voxels, obj

I have a cool 3D model I want to use, but for this program I'm working with, I need it in array form, with each point's coordinates and color value. [I've already voxelized the model using this tool](https://imagetostl.com/glb-to-voxel), but I'm not sure how to convert the voxelized .obj file into an array of coordinates and color values.

Answer (score 0):

Extract vertices and colors from voxelized OBJ file by iterating through voxels, matching to original model vertices, and storing results in an array.